# Correcting camera movement - with demonstrational video

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I have a sphere as FBX and a shader that enables me to have a texture inside of the sphere. Also inside of the sphere I have a camera. The goal is to have a simple panoramic viewer that is being driven by a headtracker.

The texture is being shown but the camera is reacting in a weird way:

When rotating the headtracker, the image is all over the place, jittery and not at all correlated to the actual movements. The headtracker input itself is correct, though.

See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7R-8XYdnZ0) for further clarification. Each time I keep the tracker steady at first and then I move it. In the second half, the first three numbers are evaluated. The other three values are gyro.

I presume the problem to be in the following code, something about the Vectors(Vector3.whatever) could be off:

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.CornflowerBlue);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in skyDome.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect ef in mesh.Effects)
            {
                float aspectRatio = (float)graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth / (float)graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight;

                Vector3 camPosition = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.Up, Quaternion.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(drehung, neigung, rollen));
                ef.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(Vector3.Zero, camPosition,Vector3.Forward);
                ef.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, aspectRatio, 0.1f, 10000.0f);
                ef.TextureEnabled = true; //Textur zulassen
                ef.Texture = panoramaTextur; //Textur auf Model darstellen
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Comment: please show a code snippet of how you control the camera (input).

Comment: See video, it's the headtracker's input.